# iOS tap counter app - more than one counter

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

I'm building an app for tap counting (for example: people going into the room).
The main goal is to be able to have multiple counters (for example: counter for main room, counter for white room, counter for green room etc.).

The app consists of:

1. A list of counters - CounterListTableViewController, with function
   is to create new items (counters) in the list
2. A counter page - RowCounterViewController

I am stuck at the moment at: Saving count number of counters with reference to item in the TableViewController.

Possible solutions:

1. Save all count numbers into an array - I don’t know how yet (a complete beginner).
2. Save all count numbers in NSUserDefaults with its index, as suggested by KudoCC in answers bellow.

Thank you!

Last edit:

```
#import "RowCounterViewController.h"

@interface RowCounterViewController ()

@end

@implementation RowCounterViewController

-(IBAction)plus {
counter=counter + 1;
count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",counter];
}
-(IBAction)minus {
counter=counter - 1;
count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",counter];
}
-(IBAction)reset {
counter=0;
count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",counter];
} 

- (void)viewDidLoad {

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(saveCount)    
name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(saveCount) 
name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification object:nil];

NSDictionary *dict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"saveCount"] ;
NSUInteger count = [dict objectForKey:@(itemIndex)] ;

//NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
//NSString *countString = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"saveCount"];
//NSLog(@"Your Count: %@",count);

//checking if data in user defaults is not empty
//if(countString.length>0)
//{
//    count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",counter];
//    counter = [countString intValue];
//}

//else
//{
//    //for first time 
//    counter = 0;
//    count.text = @"0";
//} 


//counter=0;
//count.text = @"0";
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

-(void)saveCount {
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"saveCount"] ;
NSMutableDictionary *mDict = [dict mutableCopy] ;
[mDict setObject:@(count) forKey:@(itemIndex)] ;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:mDict forKey:@"saveCount"] ;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize] ;
}

//- (void)dealloc {
//  [self saveCount] ;
//}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before   
navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
// Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

Comment: Why are you saving the count as a string instead of an integer?  Also, if you want more than one counter then you will need to store an array, not a single value

Comment: @Paulw11 thats because i am a complete beginner:) could you advise how to change for integer? I am trying to figure out how to store an array with method Ian Lan mentioned

Comment: You can just call `setInteger:forKey:` and `getIntgerForKey:` instead of set/get object

Comment: To use an array you will need to convert your integers to NSNumbers, store them in an array and then you can save it with get/set object as you are doing now

Comment: I have edited the question to be more specific, please vote to open as the question is on hold

Comment: @dicobraz `NSString *countString = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"saveCount"];`, the object for the key "saveCount" is `NSDictionary`, not `NSString`.

Comment: You'd better learn Objective-C, it's hard to help you without the basic syntax of OC.

Comment: @KudoCC yes i missed it when was pasting it, i commented this part, now its seems to have less errors, still one thing to do - to declare the itemIndex, how to declare it? I have emailed you with this question:) sorry to bother you KudoCC, I know it is probable annoying, I am trying to learn objective c at the moment, been reading apple guide on OC, it'll take some time to understand, if you have any advice on best resources to learn OC would be happy to follow. thanks

Comment: If your table view has only 1 section (I believe you have only one), the itemIndex is the `indexPath.row` of cell you selected. You should pass it to `RowCounterViewController`. In `RowCounterViewController`, you should declare a property `itemIndex` to hold the value and you use `itemIndex` to fetch the count and save the count. Apple's OC guide is good to go. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `[self saveCount]` in `dealloc` method or `viewWillDisappear:`.

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [self saveCount] ;
}
```

or:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self saveCount] ;
}
```

Update:

It seems that you want to keep the count for every item in your list. In order to achieve this, you must save the all the count in NSUserDefaults with its index, I recommend you to save `NSDictionary`  which use index as its key and count as its value. So when you push into the `RowCounterViewController`, you should tell the index number of the item, so you can get its count in NSUserDefaults. When you leave the view controller, save its count to the index.

The code below is used to fetch the count for `itemIndex`, you should tell `RowCounterViewController` the item index before push or present it.

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"saveCount"] ;
NSUInteger count = [[dict objectForKey:@(itemIndex)] unsignedIntegerValue] ;
```

The code below is used to save the count for `itemIndex`.

```
-(void)saveCount {
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"saveCount"] ;
    NSMutableDictionary *mDict = [dict mutableCopy] ;
    [mDict setObject:@(count) forKey:@(itemIndex)] ;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:mDict forKey:@"saveCount"] ;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize] ;
}
```

and next bit of code in the list view controller:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        // you can fetch the selected index path in this way.
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        RowCounterViewController *vc = (RowCounterViewController*)[segue destinationViewController];
        // the currentIndex is the itemIndex I mentioned above.
        vc.currentIndex = indexPath.row;
    }
}
```

Comment: that kind of worked, something is not right in my code though, now after i go into counter, tap lets say 2 times then go back to the tableview, when again go to the counter it shows me 0, however when tap again it goes to 3, so it remembers the value, but shows 0

Comment: @dicobraz It seems that you want to keep the count for every item in your list. In order to achieve this, you must save the all the count in `NSUserDefaults` with its index, I recommend you save `NSDictionary` which use index as its key, and count as its value. So when you push into the `RowCounterViewController`, you should tell the index number of the item, so you can get its count in `NSUserDefaults`. When you leave the view controller, save its count to the index.

Comment: i am keep messing up, cant get the code right, where i am going wrong? thanks for your help! @KudoCC added and edit above

Comment: @dicobraz My fault, it should be `NSUInteger count = [[dict objectForKey:@(itemIndex)] unsignedIntegerValue] ;`. What's wrong now ?

Comment: added a link to a screenshot, i get this error lines, i think i put the code wrong

Comment: I have tried to declare `itemIndex` a few different `@property NSString *itemIndex` as a number and object, but its not working, what is an `itemIndex`?)

Comment: @dicobraz `@property (nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger itemIndex;`, and set the selected row to it. `vc.itemIndex = indexPath.row;` in `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` of table view controller.

Comment: this line `NSUInteger count = [dict objectForKey:@(itemIndex)] unsignedIntegerValue] ;` still gives an error - "use of undeclared identifier 'itemIndex': did you mean '_itemIndex'" if i change it to `@(_itemIndex)` it gives an error "unused variable count"

Comment: @dicobraz You can send your project to my email, I'll modify the code and send back to you. I don't think you get the main idea...

Comment: it compiles and works now, i had to reset content and settings in iPhone simulator to override `dict` thank you very much KudoCC!

Answer (score 0):

if you have more than one counter, you need an array to store all counter , and use `UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDatasource` to present counters for rows in the tableview.

save the array to a file with this method

```
[array writeToFile:arrayFileName atomically:YES];
```

or you can use anything you can come up with to store it in

```
dealloc or viewWillDisappear
```

if you want to communicate between your `tableview` and `RowCounterViewController`, say `RowCounterViewController` passing the counter number back to `tableview` and present it in the related item, you can use delegate or notification.

that's something you need to learn in the future.

you can find some demo about it.

good luck.

Comment: thats something i still need to learn, trying to figure the store array method, any additional help would be much appreciated, thank you